# install Pycuda 2013.1.1 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: cuda, gpu, pycuda

I followed instructions [here](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Windows#Windows_7_64-bit_with_Visual_Studio_Professional_2008_.28Strictly_Binary_Versions.29) . I have installed all packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (all the latest one).

It seems I installed successfully. I ran the code below in Ipython:

```
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(numpy.random.randn(4,4).astype(numpy.float32))  ## pass
a_doubled = (2*a_gpu).get()  ## the line can't be passed with Ipython
```

and got this error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py", line 137, in compile_plain
>         lcase_err_text = (stdout+stderr).decode("utf-8").lower()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 109: invalid start byte

How to solve this issue? I have struggled several days.

Comment: Is the problem only in IPython?

Comment: how to test this case?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been caused by an error handling issue inside PyCUDA when code contains unparseable unicode. The bug was [fixed](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/issues/37) in late 2013 and should have been pushed in the PyCUDA 2014.1 release.

[This answer was added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list for the CUDA and PyCUDA tags]